# Increase bulk Index requests performance of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, go, goroutine, elasticsearch-bulk-api

tl;dr: Currently, I am using Elasticsearch 5.6 as a data store for my go application. I have a million documents spread in 12 indices. Each index has 5 shards and 2 replicas. First, I load those docs from Elasticsearch and then process them and then index them in bulk with 10000 docs/batch rate. I run 3 workers which have one async goroutine per worker at a time. Those goroutines are per index so they send bulk index requests per index. That means a worker sends around 100,000 docs in a goroutine. The docs are sent in batches, each goroutine sends almost 10 batches. This entire stuff takes more than a minute. Most of the time is taken in bulk indexing.

My current Elasticsearch is running with 6GB RAM and 3.5GB heap size. I tried to tune Elasticsearch to improve indexing speed by increasing index buffer size to 20% ie. 700MB. I disabled indexing for fields which don't need indexing. I optimised numeric fields types in mappings. I disabled _all field. I changed index codec (compression method) to best_compression. After doing all this, there is not much improvement.

So I would like to get ideas to improve bulk indexing performance to finish all process within a minute. Will it be improved if I add more RAM and heap size to Elasticsearch? Any other settings/tuning?

Right now, I am in development phase so I can switch to other data store system as well which can suit my requirements of reading, writing and analyzing data in quick time. Such ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on Server Fault. You should also describe your node topology. For instance, one or more dedicated Ingest nodes may improve indexing performance. Also, for 80k documents per index (assuming even distribution) 5 shards seems very excessive. Do you really have 15 nodes or more?

Comment: @Peter I have 4 nodes

Comment: Having more than one shard of any given index on a single node makes generally no sense (and impacts performance negatively). Reduce to one shard per index for starters.